# How to show tooltip on disabled dates of jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquerydatetimepicker

I am trying to add tooltip on some disabled dates as holiday reason but unable get them displayed when hovered. i have even tried adding custom hover function but no success.

```
availableDates = ["09/04/2018", "09/05/2018", "09/06/2018", "08/31/2018", "09/01/2018"];
holidays_dates = { "09/02/2018": "sgsdf", "05/27/2018": "home sick", "08/20/2018": "fcg", "05/26/2018": "i dont know", "05/25/2018": "home sick" }

function available(date) {

    var moth = String(date.getMonth() + 1);
    if (moth.length == 1) {
        moth = "0" + moth;
    }

    var dat = String(date.getDate());
    if (dat.length == 1) {
        dat = "0" + dat;
    }
    dmy = moth + "/" + dat + "/" + date.getFullYear();

    if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else if (dmy in holidays_dates) {
        console.log(dmy)
        return [false, "Highlighted", holidays_dates[dmy]];
    } else {
        return [false, ""];
    }
}


$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (dt) {
        return available(dt);
    },
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
        getslots(dateText, selected_consultant);
    }
});
```

the holidays_dates variable consists of disabled date and reason and is perfectly adding the reason to the title of the  element

```
<td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled Highlighted" title="home sick">
    <span class="ui-state-default">25</span>
</td>
```

as above holiday reason added in title attribute of  tag but hovering on that date does not show tooltip

Comment: You are on the right track. The third element of the array returned by function that is called by `beforeShowDay` is the tooltip text. So returning `[false, "", "Fathers Day"]` would show "Fathers Day" on hover of the disabled date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable the date and show tooltip use option beforeShowDay.

```
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
    var formattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date),
        checkDisable = disabledDates.indexOf(formattedDate) == -1;

    if(checkDisable == true){
        return [checkDisable];
    }else{
    //add ui-datepicker-unselectable class to the disabled date.
      return [!checkDisable,'ui-datepicker-unselectable',holidays_dates[formattedDate]];
    }
}
```

and customize the css of the disabled date

```
function changeDisableDateColor(){
    var unselectableDate = $('.ui-datepicker-unselectable a');

    unselectableDate.css({
        background: 'red',
        cursor: 'context-menu',
        border: 0
    });
}
```

call the above function i.e changeDisableDateColor when date field is clicked.
    `$('#datepicker').click(function() {
        changeDisableDateColor();
});`

and also inside onChangeMonthYear (detects the change in month or year) option

```
onChangeMonthYear: function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    changeDisableDateColor();
  });
}
```

setTimeout is used because the jquery ui removes all the dates item and add again, so we wait until we have right date. Without setTimeout `var unselectableDate = $('.ui-datepicker-unselectable a');` will give previous date.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xx4GS/1225/

Hope I answered the question.

Edited:

There was bug, when day or month is of single digit ie 1-9 then the date does not get matched and will not be disabled.

```
if(month.toString().length == 1){
    month = '0'+month.toString();
}

if(day.toString().length == 1){
    day = '0'+ day.toString();
}
```

Fixed the bug by adding 0 in front of day and month.

Here is the solved js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lf5p3hct/2/

Comment: How would you implement `noWeekends` functionality? I would like to have the tooltip only on the holidays, so weekends should be just disabled.

Comment: check for weekends inside beforeShowDay and add that date to the disabledDates array.

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/49vpmsg6/3/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with JQuery 3.3.1. I solved this by just adding CSS. 
Try adding the following in your CSS file:

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar > .ui-state-disabled.Highlighted {
    pointer-events: initial;
}
```

This will remove the attribute `pointer-events: none;` that is set by the CSS class `ui-state-disabled`.

`Hightlighted` part in the CSS has to be changed to whatever CSS class that you add to the date field in `beforeShowDay()`.